# generic soap client tool

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui, soap-client

I have created a soap service which I want to test.But I dont want to create a soap client for testing it.I am looking for some tool which can parse wsdl and give list of parameters which can be inputted and then gives response from soap service.

I know of [soap panda](http://www.soappanda.com) , but it does not work,says invalid url as my soap service url has a hyphen in it.

[SoapUi](http://www.soapui.org) is very large in size.I want a small tool which I can easily download

[soapclient](http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html) is a web tool,but it is down.

Please suggest some alternative tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [POSTER](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/poster/) firefox-addon might be what your looking for. :S

Comment: Poster is too generic,it does not parse wsdl and give a list of parameters to set

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. http://www.service-repository.com/client/start or
2. http://membrane-soa.org/soap-client/

The 2nd is better for me, but it doesn't work with SSL.

Ciao.